# Can I change the current cursor from an inactive application?

Tags: cocoa, macos, mouse-cursor, nscursor, nstrackingarea

I’ve got a utility Mac application that runs in the background (`LSUIElement` enabled). Under some condition this application displays a menu window with several buttons. The problem is that when I hover over this window the mouse cursor still behaves according to the application beneath it – when there’s text under the menu, cursor changes to the insertion “I beam” shape.

Obviously I’d prefer a regular pointer arrow. I’ve dived into `NSTrackingArea` and friends after a bit of hacking I can detect the mouse-enter and mouse-exit events. But when I try to change the current cursor using `NSCursor` on mouse enter, nothing happens. Looks like the machine refuses to change cursor from an inactive application, because when I activate the application before the mouse-enter event, the cursor changes.

I don’t want to switch the active application just to change the cursor. Is there a way to fiddle with the cursor from an inactive application?

P.S. Same problem on cocoa-dev: [one](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/77063-setting-the-cursor-when-not-active-frontmost-app.html), [two](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/117925-nscursor-set-not-setting-the-cursor.html).

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to this too.  Did you ever find anything?

Comment: @zadam: No. Fortunately we have changed the application concept anyway, so that we got rid of this requirement.

Comment: Same problem here. Oddly, before I converted my app from Carbon (HI windows) to Cocoa, I could successfully change the cursor using NSCursor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid this is not possible due the OS X restrictions.